# Flask always send post request

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have coded the below form and controller but when the page is loaded, the page automatically send request to my database. How to change the form or controller and just send request when I clicked create button.

**html code:**

```
 <form method="POST" action="/conference/create">
          <div class="field">
             <div class="control">
         <input class="input is-large" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" autofocus="">
              </div>
           </div>
          
          <input class="input is-large" type="text" name="shortname" placeholder="Your Shortname">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year">
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**controller function:**

```
@main.route('/conference/create', methods=['POST','GET'])
@login_required
def create_conference():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    shortname = request.form.get('shortname')
    year = request.form.get('year')
    startdate = request.form.get('startdate')
    enddate = request.form.get('enddate')
    submissiondeadline = request.form.get('submissiondeadline')
    website = request.form.get('website')
    tag = request.form.get('tag')

    datem = datetime.today().replace(day=1)

    conference = Conference(confid="1", creationdatetime=datem, name=name, shortname=shortname, year=year, startdate=startdate,
                            enddate=enddate, submissiondeadline=submissiondeadline, creatoruser=12, website=website)

    conferenceTag = ConferenceTags("1", tag)

    db.session.add(conference)
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.add(conferenceTag)
    db.session.commit()

    return render_template('create_conference.html')
```

By the way, I have changed controller's method parameters with just 'POST' when I do that it gives me not allowed methods error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add an if statement to specify if the incoming request is POST or GET and act accordingly.

```
   if request.method=='GET':
       #load page
   elif request.method=='POST':
       #update database
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I am newbie on flask. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@main.route('/conference/create', methods=['POST','GET'])
@login_required
def create_conference():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        shortname = request.form.get('shortname')
        year = request.form.get('year')
        startdate = request.form.get('startdate')
        enddate = request.form.get('enddate')
        submissiondeadline = request.form.get('submissiondeadline')
        website = request.form.get('website')
        tag = request.form.get('tag')

        datem = datetime.today().replace(day=1)

        conference = Conference(confid="1", creationdatetime=datem, name=name, shortname=shortname, year=year, startdate=startdate,
                                enddate=enddate, submissiondeadline=submissiondeadline, creatoruser=12, website=website)

        conferenceTag = ConferenceTags("1", tag)

        db.session.add(conference)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.add(conferenceTag)
        db.session.commit()
        return 'you want to do.'
    return render_template('create_conference.html')
```